# Find a differential equation from data set

Tags: differential-equations, fitting

I'm trying to fit a differential equation to a large dataset, but I'm not achieving anything.

This is my dataset

[image]

and my differential equation/model is

```
100*y''[t] + k1*y[t] + k2*y'[t] - 981 == 0
```

I was trying to solve it with ParametricNDSolveValue without good results.

Comment: `DSolve` can solve the differential equation. The solution could then be use as the model for `NonlinearModelFit` to fit your data.

Comment: Looks like OP has a spectrum and not original data, so probably he needs reconstruct signal (inverse fourier or the like) and then fit with analytical solution to DE.

Comment: Thanks @BobHanlon, I'm going to try that.

Comment: On the other hand, thanks @AIx as well. I have original data in a spreadsheet, but it's fairly big that I couldn't share it here; I think I have to use a hyperlink.